# The type in a dynamic_cast must be a pointer or reference to a complete class type, or void *

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

I am hoping there is someone out there who understands why the code below fails. I am trying to get an instance of PositionAttitudeTransform (Openscenegraph class) from an osg::Node* node object. But there is the compiler error below in bold.

```
 void CameraPosCallbackUpdate::operator()(osg::Node* node, osg::NodeVisitor* nv)
{ 
   // other code goes here

    osg::PositionAttitudeTransform* pat = dynamic_cast<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform*> (node);

}
```

**IntelliSense: the type in a dynamic_cast must be a pointer or reference to a complete class type, or void ***

Please help me with correct way to access my object and I would appreciate help in understanding what the problem here is since I believe the cast should be possible.

[image: Hierarchy]
http://www.openscenegraph.org/documentation/OpenSceneGraphReferenceDocs/a00529.html

Comment: You need to show the declaration of `node`. As the error message says, it should be a pointer or reference to a complete type.

Comment: code updated with more detail on where node is coming from.

Comment: Is the type, in fact, complete? Is a definition for it visible from here?

Comment: As compiler said to you you have not included osg::PositionAttitudeTransform implementation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you have to `#include` the header file which contains the body of `class osg::PositionAttitudeTransform`.
`dynamic_cast` gives such error when the body of the destination class is not visible.

Here is the similar [error reproduced in g++](http://ideone.com/9uZoUl).

Comment: Thank you. I had to remove the #include <osg/Transform> and replaced it with #include <osg/PositionAttitudeTransform>.