# Forward declare an abstract class from a different namespace

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces, forward-declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The type in a dynamic_cast must be a pointer or reference to a complete class type, or void *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133407/the-type-in-a-dynamic-cast-must-be-a-pointer-or-reference-to-a-complete-class-ty)

I've got a namespace Fuzzy and it has an abstract class called CuteDog (that inherits from another abstract class).

I'm writing a new class called PuppyArmy

I'd like to have a pointer to a CuteDog in PuppyArmy and in my header file I'm trying this.

```
namespace Fuzzy { class CuteDog }

using namespace Fuzzy;

class PuppyArmy { 
  ...
  CuteDog *cute;
}
```

then when in my cpp file i've got this

```
using namespace Tough;

....
cute = dynamic_cast<::Fuzzy::CuteDog*>(foo()); // where foo() returns the parent class of CuteDog*
```

The compiler is telling me

```
 C2440: '=' : cannot convert from Fuzzy::CuteDog * to PuppyArmy::Fuzzy::CuteDog *
```

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try changing `dynamic_cast<::Fuzzy..` to `dynamic_cast< ::Fuzzy...` because my compiler thinks the `<:` is the beginning of a trigraph/digraph.

Comment: Once I fixed your transcription errors, it [works fine](http://ideone.com/qP50mX) for me. I think perhaps you're not telling us something. Please post a short, complete program that demonstrates your error. http://SSCCE.ORG/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didnt include header file where you defines `CuteDog` implementation

Comment: CuteDog is part of an API we use but don't have access to the source.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is lead here by the title. This is how to forward declare a class (abstract or not) from a different name space:

```
namespace different {
  class SomeClass;
}
```